# Update progress bar from sub-routine

Tags: python, progress-bar, mainwindow

I would like to update a progress bar that I have on a main window with the progress of a task that I am doing on another sub-routine, would it be possible??

To be as clear as possible, I would have 2 files:

In my **Mainwindow.py** I would have something like:

```
import Calculations

#some code
self.ui.progressBar
Calculations.longIteration("parameters")
```

Then I would have a separate file for the calculations: **Calculations.py**

```
def longIteration("parameters")

#some code for the loop

"here I would have a loop running"
"And I would like to update the progressBar in Mainwindow"
```

Is that possible?

Or it should be done on a different way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest of methods would be to simply pass the GUI object:

```
self.ui.progressBar
Calculations.longIteration("parameters", self.ui.progressBar)
```

and update `progressBar` on `Calculations`. This has two problems, though:

- You're mixing GUI code with `Calculations`, who probably shouldn't know anything about it
- if  `longIteration` is a long running function, as its name implies, you're blocking your GUI main thread, which will make many GUI frameworks unhappy (and your application unresponsive).

Another solution is running `longIteration` in a thread, and pass a callback function that you use to update your progress bar:

```
import threading
def progress_callback():
    #update progress bar here
threading.Thread(target=Calculations.longIteration, args=["parameters", progress_callback]).run()
```

then, inside `longIteration`, do:

```
def longIteration( parameters, progress_callback ):
    #do your calculations
    progress_callback() #call the callback to notify of progress
```

You can modify the `progress_callback` to take arguments if you need them, obviously

Comment: Hi Goncalopp, thanks for your answer. You are right about the first option. I took that first option because it looked easier for me, but, yes, the MainWindow becomes unresponsive, so the progressBar does not update until the end of the loop. So my problem with your second option, the one with a thread is that I do not fully understand how to update the progressBar with the progress of the loop from the thread

Comment: @newPyUser You need to call the callback from `longIteration`. I've edited the question to make it clear